# Did David's judgment between Mephibosheth and Ziba foreshadow Solomon's judgment between the two mothers?

Tags: david, solomon, typology

In 2 Samuel 19, David asks Mephibosheth why he did not join him and Ziba when they fled from Absalom. Ziba claimed that Mephibosheth intended to claim the throne, and Mephibosheth claimed that Ziba had abandoned him. David decided to divide Mephibosheth's property between him and Ziba.

In the same manner, Solomon decided to divide the child between the two mothers. Mephibosheth objected to the division of his property:

> "And Mephibosheth said to the king, ´Oh, let him take it all, since my lord the king has come safely home.´" [2 Samuel 19:30 ESV](https://my.bible.com/bible/59/2SA.19.30.ESV).

In the same manner, when Solomon ordered the child to be divided, the mother objected, asking that the child be given wholly to the other woman.

Are we to see a parallel here, and what does this show us about Christ?

Comment: Also worth mentioning is the 2 Kings 6:24–33 passage with the two women in a dispute over the remains of one of their children.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something, to be learnt by the comparison however I was surprised at how different - at the word level - these two accounts are:

1. David calls for the lands to be תַּחְלְק֖וּ (shared), while the baby is to be גִּזְר֛וּ (split) into two.
2. Mephibosheth is happy for the other to יִֽקַּֽח (take), while the mother is content for the baby to be תְּנוּ (given) to the other.

I doubt, therefore, that these passages are intended to be contrasts. Instead, 1 Kings 3:16-28 is to illustrate that Solomon is wise. If the two texts matched, then 19:29-30 might be viewed as illustrating, that David is unwise, but they do not.

Instead, wisdom is only one of the areas where David fell here. He is also impatient, somewhat dishonest here, and suffering because of previous rashness. Solomon is wise, but he also takes the time to judge fairly. He has not gotten himself in a mire, and become frustrated by it. And, yet, as the history makes clear, it is still David who was the great founding king. It is still the Son of **David** that was awaited.

Do they tell us things about the Messiah? If we know that the Messiah will be the greatest of all the kings of Israel, then he must be wiser than Solomon. And he must be more good than David. He must, in short, be God.

Comment: I wonder if Solomon was thinking about the incident with Mephibosheth when the two women came to him, and he decided to suggestive the same solution, but this time as a bluff.

Answer (score 1):

Your stance on this question makes perfect sense. I have often wondered about the truth between Miohibosheth and Ziba. Ziba made this accusation when Miphibosheth was not there to defend himself, Ziba stood to gain great favor by the accusation if proven true. Miphibosheth's conduct and answer, stand in stark contrast to Ziba's. Ziba was present when confronted by David , Mephibosheth knew no one could come before David and lie, "he was as an Angel of God" . Mephibosheth could be an "Oscar winning actor" Jesus was in David and it would have failed. Mephibosheth's response was instant and from the heart, Miphibosheth loved David as did Jonathan. The same can not be said for Ziba.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/44915)

Answer (score 0):

**Did these two accounts have a parallel?**

1. David decided to divide Mephibosheth's property between him and Ziba and Mephibosheth willing to let Ziba take it all.
2. Solomon decided to split the child and the child's mother willing to let the other woman take the child.

The answer is "No". They were not a parallel nor did any implication that Solomon did this in learning from his father. The reason is straight forward;

1. Property can be divided but a child cannot.
2. David had wrongly judged to give Ziba all belongings of Mephibosheth (2 Samuel 16:4) without hearing Mephibosheth's testimony, but Solomon heard both women testimony before made his judgement. So David's judgement in 2 Samuel 19 was a correction to his previous mistake, that Mephibosheth did not think it was necessary.

The scenario was so different that hardly I would believe there was any connection.

**Did they show anything about Christ?**

Again the answer is "No". For it didn't have any messianic message hidden in the stories, or at least I can't find anyone says there is.